# Project client/server (react/node) problem with git

Tags: reactjs, git, express, github

I'm doing my first project with both the client and server side. So the first thing I did was to create a repo in GitHub and started my project with `cd client`, `npm create vite`, (react/typescript), `npm i`. Then I did a new terminal `cd server`, `npm init --y`, `install express`.

Pushed to Git Hub. All files belonging to these two folders are there.

Then I shut down vs code and when I got back to continue I did as I always do when working with React. Copied repo URL to my vs code, wrote in terminal: `cd client`, `npm install`. But when I do this, I get:

> npm ERR! code ENOENT
> npm ERR! syscall open
> npm ERR! path /Users/rikkekristiansen/Documents/uppgift/imageSearch-1/imageSearch/client/package.json
> npm ERR! errno -2
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/rikkekristiansen/Documents/uppgift/imageSearch-1/imageSearch/client/package.json'
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> npm ERR! enoent

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/rikkekristiansen/.npm/_logs/2024-03-07T12_05_31_229Z-debug-0.log
> rikkekristiansen@MBPsomthorRikke client %

What can I do to work with my project?
I thougt that with two folders I just have to create two terminals and install the necessary packages and then I can work. Can somebody guide me to do it right?
Thanks

Comment: I don't think `npm` erroring has anything to do with git, or github?